# Set var value from other JavaScript file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, reset, thickbox

I have a two JavaScript files:

1. Main.js
2. Pmt.js

I'm also using [thick box](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) (Ajax call)

**in Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var cnt=0;

$("#btnPmt").click(function(){
    cnt=cnt+1;
    tb_show('Void Transaction','pmt.jsp?height=310&width=400', null);
});


});
```

The **Pmt.js** file is included in pmt.jsp as

```
<script src="js/Pmt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**in Pmt.js**

```
 $("#btnPmtClose").click(function(){
    cnt=0;
    parent.tb_remove();
});
```

How we can reset the value of **var cnt** in **Pmt.js** that decalred in **Main.js**?
The above is not working, when I close the thickbox, I find the incremented value, not zero that set on close, even Ajax call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Main.js make `cnt` as **global** var by moving it outside any function :

```
var cnt=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
})
```